# How to put horizontal Table and Text side by side in Latex?

Tags: tables, rotating, sidewaystable

I have a table that is horizontal is the code is below, But how to put this table and text side by side as we can see in the book, please let me know as soon as possible. Thank you for the help.

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Resource Potential \& Metal Production estimation \cite{sharma2011deep}}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}[H]
\hline
\textbf{Metal} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Mean \\ Concentration\end{tabular}}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Resource\\  Potential t\\ (million tonnes)\end{tabular}}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Metal Production\\  per Year (mi.t)\end{tabular}}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Price of Metal\\ (\$/kg)\end{tabular}}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Gross In-Place\\  Value of Metal\\ \$/year\end{tabular}}} \\ \hline
Dry Nodules & 55\% of wet nodule   & 206,250,000 & -       & -     & -             \\ \hline
Manganese   & 24\% of dry nodule   & 49,500,000  & 360,000 & 1.32  & 475,200,000   \\ \hline
Nickel      & 1.1\% of dry nodule  & 2,268,750   & 16,500  & 23.00 & 379,500,000   \\ \hline
Copper      & 1.04\% of dry nodule & 2,145,000   & 15,600  & 8.30  & 129,480,000   \\ \hline
Cobalt      & 0.1\% of dry nodule  & 206,250     & 1,500   & 39.20 & 58,800,000    \\ \hline
Total       & 26.24\%              & 54,120,000  & 393,600 &       & 1,042,980,000 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages you currently use. (See also: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) Regarding: "table and text side by side as we can see in the book": Which book as you referring to? Most likely, a sketch of the exected output would help clarify your question. Could you add such a sketch to your question?

Comment: The `[H]` in `\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}[H]` looks like it's goint to cause errors. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Welcome! Besides others' comments, `sidewaystable` is meant to appear in a separate page on its own, so no text is expected to be put side-by-side with such a table.

Comment: Okay I did not know that, I can change that but How to make it side by side with text?

Comment: Take a look at the `wrapfig` package (`> texdoc wrapfig`).

Comment: I thought it is just for figure/Picture; I will try and comment if it is working.